# Which implementation is preferred for real time video object detection with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorflow-serving, object-detection-api

I want to implement a real time video object detection where streams of video frames are fed to a detection serving system. I am considering two ways of implementing the system: (1) using tensorflow serving system [TF serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving), (2) using tensorflow session.run(). I was wondering which implementation fits following scenario better?

- Video streams arrive to the detection system at random time. Each of the video stream lasts for some time.
- the system must support concurrent video object detection processes in real time. But the GPU nodes are limited which meaning more than one detection processes may be running on a GPU concurrently.
- Multiple DNN models can be used for achieving detections. when a new video stream just arrives, one of the DNN models is selected for inference. It is desired that the detection system can change the model selection decision on the fly.
- the system is able to set resource allocation (maximum GPU utilization) for each serving model.

Thank you!

Comment: First you have to create a handler to either queue up or send for process. For concurrent detection, you can always queue them up if you only have limited GPU. But there would be latency. Usually you have to estimate the traffic and place enough hardware for it.  Multiple DNN models and real-time, you can always try to place the network side by side in a single model. Then with the input in, first divide the probelm and conquer.  In this way you dont have to drop/reset the GPU and run another model . The last one I doubt maximum GPU utilization is achivable or not. Its difficult even for game

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai thanks! placing the DNNs in a single model is a good idea. But the combined DNN model would be consuming more GPU memory, right? As for the implementation (Tensorflow Serving or Tensorflow Session.run() ), which one you think would be better for my case.

Comment: I never try with tensorflow serving method. I tried the combine model method before and it works. last time I have to predict depth map and semantic map together. So I combine 2 net together.  In your case, if no data, just send black image. There need more memory but throughput should be high. For  Session.run() method, not sure whether they need to w8 and load or not. If it can perform seemlessly then go for that one. I never see the bottom layer implemnation.